# How to Iterate an nested dictionary using map function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to iterate an dictionary using map. But i could not able to get the nested dictionary properties.  For example i need the key where value.type==string.can anyone help me with this?

data.js

```
const products_schema = {
    _id: {
        auto: true
    },
    product_name: {
        auto: false,
        type: "string",
        min: 5,
        max: 10,
        special_characters: ['_', ' '],
        numbers: true,
        alphabet: true,
        required: true,
        correct: ""
    },
    product_image: {
        auto: false,
        type: "array:string",
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        required: true
    },
    product_specification: {
        auto: false,
        type: "array:specification_schema",
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        required: true
    }
}
}
let schema=new Map()
schema.set('products_schema',products_schema)
for([key,value] of schema.entries()){
    console.log(value.type)  //shows undefined in the console
}
```

Comment: what is your expected o/p and what framework are you using

Comment: I need to auto generate the value for the key(product_name) with matching all the conditions(min,max,splchar,type). My expected output is to find the type of the product_name key.@AkhilAravind

Comment: didnt get you, can you elobrate

Comment: Your comment is unclear. Do you want to get key with `type = string` (which is `product_name`)? Why do you need `Map`? What does this mean-> *"with matching all the conditions(min,max,splchar,type)*"

Comment: Firstly, I need to sort by type. then if a type is string i have to generate a string by satisfying given min, max conditions @adiga

Comment: There is no mention of `sort` or min & max condition in the question. Please create a [mcve] with proper input, desired output with a clear problem statement

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to iterate this map would be to use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as so:

```js
var products_schema = {
    _id: {
        auto: true
    },
    product_name: {
        auto: false,
        type: "string",
        min: 5,
        max: 10,
        special_characters: ['_', ' '],
        numbers: true,
        alphabet: true,
        required: true,
        correct: ""
    },
    product_image: {
        auto: false,
        type: "array:string",
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        required: true
    },
    product_specification: {
        auto: false,
        type: "array:specification_schema",
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        required: true
    }
}
Object.keys(products_schema).forEach(key => console.log(products_schema[key].type));
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you need to use the Map object, but for this case of iterating through objects, you can try the good old [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop, which iterates through the enumerable properties of your `products_schema` object.

```js
const products_schema = {
    _id: {
        auto: true
    },
    product_name: {
        auto: false,
        type: "string",
        min: 5,
        max: 10,
        special_characters: ['_', ' '],
        numbers: true,
        alphabet: true,
        required: true,
        correct: ""
    },
    product_image: {
        auto: false,
        type: "array:string",
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        required: true
    },
    product_specification: {
        auto: false,
        type: "array:specification_schema",
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        required: true
    }
};

for (const key in products_schema){
  console.log(key);
  for (const inner in products_schema[key]){
    console.log(`${inner}:${products_schema[key][inner]}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: In case if i have multiple objects like products_schema , specification_schema, In that case how can i iterate?

Comment: @hariprasanth Hmmm.. Having multiple objects. Are all of these objects assigned to different variables?

Comment: const specification_schema = {
    brand: {
        auto: false,
        type: "string",
        min: 10,
        max: 50,
        special_characters: ['_', ' '],
        numbers: true,
        alphabet: true,
        required: true
    },
    color: {
        auto: false,
        type: "string",
        min: 10,
        max: 50,
        special_characters: ['_', ' '],
        numbers: true,
        alphabet: true,
        required: true
    },
}

Comment: I see.. Why not just iterate through that variable as well? The very same way I have done it with `products_schema`

Comment: In this case i have to give variable names everytime. I thought of assign a key to every variable using map and iterate with that. so that i cannot give the variable name.

Comment: Ahh.. Okay, I understand. So what you wanna do is to populate the Map with the above objects, followed by iterating through the key-value pairs of the Map to print out the properties and all?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Map()` isn't always the best solution, although I have to admit in circumstances where you know the name of the key you want it's great, but to get a birds-eye view of a Map's content is a little more involved.

In the following demo we will use:

1. `objToMap(object)`: Using `Object.entries()` and destructure the result within a `for...of` loop. Each iteration is a simple `.set()`. A complete Map is returned.
2. `displayMap(Map)`: Displaying all paths of the Map we'll use two `for..of` loops. The outer loop will address each key/value of Map. The inner loop will address each key/value of the value extracted from the outer loop.
3. `getPath(Map, root, prop)`: The second parameter is the Map key (ex. `'product_name'`). The third parameter is the key within the object of second parameter (ex. 'type'). Once the second parameter is found with `Map.get()` a destructuring `for...of` loop of `Map.entries()` is filtered by `.filter()` and the result from `Object.fromEntries()` is returned.

```js
let products_schema = {
  _id: {
    auto: true
  },
  product_name: {
    auto: false,
    type: "string",
    min: 5,
    max: 10,
    special_characters: ['_', ' '],
    numbers: true,
    alphabet: true,
    required: true,
    correct: ""
  },
  product_image: {
    auto: false,
    type: "array:string",
    min: 0,
    max: 50,
    required: true
  },
  product_specification: {
    auto: false,
    type: "array:specification_schema",
    min: 0,
    max: 50,
    required: true
  }
}

function objToMap(obj) {
  let map = new Map();
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    map.set(key, value);
  }
  return map;
}

let x = objToMap(products_schema);

// Display all map paths

function displayMap(Map) {
  for (let [key, value] of Map.entries()) {
    for (let [prop, val] of Object.entries(value)) {
      console.log(key + ': ' + prop + ': ' + val);
    }
  }
}

displayMap(x);

function getPath(Map, root, prop) {
  let level1 = Map.has(root) ? Map.get(root) : {};
  const filtered = Object.entries(level1)
    .filter(([key, value]) => key.includes(prop));
  return Object.fromEntries(filtered);
}

let y = getPath(x, 'product_name', 'type');
console.log(y);

// if root or prop is not found an empty object is returned
let z = getPath(x, 'product_name', 'foo');
console.log(z);
```